# Is Python heading statically typed programming language?

Tags: python

My goal is to understand how Python handle type. I found out that Python have similar way to describe type like TypeScript. However, when I tried to misuse the function e.g `Speak(1.0)`. The IDE nor the `python main.py` will panic. It will still invoke the function although the function arg is a float.

main.py

```
def Speak(input: str | int) -> TypeError | None:
    if type(input) != str and type(input) != int:
        return TypeError("type not supported")

    if type(input) == str:
        print("str")
        return
    elif type(input) == int:
        print("int")
        return

Speak(1.0)
```

Comment: Those are just cosmetic, and also helps to work in an IDE (provides completion and suggestions of possible methods based on the object type hint)

Comment: They're called type hints incase you wanted to google them. They're not enforced during runtime

Comment: @Alexey They're more than "cosmetic", they're just not enforced at runtime.

Comment: *My* IDE does warn about "expected int, got float" with this type hint…

Comment: @deceze do you use VS code? if so, do you use a specific linter.

Comment: I use PyCharm...